# What is Node.js cluster best practice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

Is it better to write our server logic before forking workers or after?

I'll give two examples below to make it clear.

example #1:

```
const express = require("express");
const cluster = require('cluster');
const app = express();

app.get("/path", somehandler);

if (cluster.Master)
  // forking workers..
else
  app.listen(8000);
```

or example #2:

```
const cluster = require('cluster');

if (cluster.Master)
  // forking workers..
else {
  const express = require("express");
  const app = express();

  app.get("/path", somehandler);

  app.listen(8000);
}
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. Since when You call `cluster.fork()` it calls `child_process.fork` on [same entry file](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/cluster/master.js#L51)  and keeps child process handler for interprocess communication.

Read following methods defined at lines following of [cluster's master](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/cluster/master.js) module: [167](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/cluster/master.js#L167), [102](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/cluster/master.js#L102), [51](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/cluster/master.js#L51), [52](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/cluster/master.js#L52)

Let's get back to Your code:

1. In example **#1** it assigns variables, creates app instance both for master and child processes, then checks for process master or not.
2. In example **#2** it checks for process master or not and if not it assigns vars, creates app instance and binds listener on port for child workers.

In fact it will do the same operations in clild processes:

1. assigning vars
2. creating app instance
3. starting listener

My own best practices using cluster is has 2 steps:

**Step 1** - having custom cluster wrapper in separate module and wrapping in application call:

Have `cluster.js` file:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (callable) => {
  const
    cluster = require('cluster'),
    numCpu = require('os').cpus().length;

  const handleDeath = (deadWorker) {
    console.log('worker ' + deadWorker.process.pid + ' dead');

    const worker = cluster.fork();
    console.log('re-spawning worker ' + worker.process.pid);
  }
  
  process.on('uncaughtException',
    (err) => {
      console.error('uncaughtException:', err.message);
      console.error(err.stack);
    });

  cluster.on('exit', handleDeath);
  
  // no need for clustering if there is just 1 cpu
  if (numCpu === 1 || !cluster.isMaster) {
    return callable();
  }
  
  // saving 1 cpu for master process (1 M + N instances) 
  // or create 2 instances since 1 M + 1 Instance 
  // is ineffective when respawning instance
  // better to have 1 M + 2 instances if cpu count 2
  const instances = numCpu > 2 ? numCpu - 1 : numCpu; 

  console.log('Starting', instances, 'instances');
  for (let i = 0; i < instances; i++, cluster.fork());
};
```

Keep `app.js` simple like this for modularity and testability (read about `supertest`):

```
'use strict';

const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/path", somehandler);

module.exports = app;
```

Serving the app at some port must be handled by different module, so have `server.js` look like this:

```
'use strict';

const start = require('./cluster');

start(() => {
  
  const http = require('http');
  const app = require('./app');


  const listenHost = process.env.HOST || '127.0.0.1';
  const listenPort = process.env.PORT || 8080;
  const httpServer = http.createServer(app);

  httpServer.listen(listenPort, listenHost,
      () => console.log('App listening at http://'+listenHost+':'+listenPort));
});
```

You may add in `package.json` such line in `scripts` section:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node server.js",
  "watch": "nodemon server.js",
  ...
}
```

Run the app using:

`node server.js`, `nodemon server.js`

or

`npm start`, `npm run watch`

**Step 2** - when needed containerization:

Keep code structure like in **Step 1** and use `docker`

Cluster module will get cpu resources which provided by container orkestrator

and as an extra You'll have ability to scale docker instances on demand using `docker swarm`, `kubernetes`, `dc/os` and etc.

`Dockerfile` :

```
FROM node:alpine

ENV PORT=8080
EXPOSE $PORT

ADD ./ /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache bash git openssh

RUN npm i
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: If someone doing downvote I kindly ask to point me what I'm doing wrong in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply, but what about the memory? as I know that each worker has independant memory, so if i instantiate the app and other variables after forking will that consume more memory? and if I didn't will these variables be shared among workers?

Comment: `each worker has independant memory` - yes, because of `child_process.fork`.   `if i instantiate the app and other variables after forking will that consume more memory?` - when You call `cluster.fork` it calls `child_process.fork` and runs same file again. depending how You've wrote variable instantiation it may be consumed on child or on master process. So example #2 is more recommended.

Comment: `instances` variable in first code block doesn't seem to be defined anywhere, is it supposed to be `numCPUs` instead?

Comment: @G07cha nice catch, so I've updated my code